# Disable sound safe level notification in android

Tags: android

In My android App I need to raise the volume and when I raise I get a notification like this:

"Raise volume above safe level ?
Listening at high volume for long periods may damage your hearing"

How can I disable this function ?

Comment: Those popups are there because of a legal requirement from the European Union. It's not possible to disable them as far as I know. The user will have to dismiss them by pressing "OK" or whatever options the popup gives him/her.

Comment: The most frustrating thing about this warning is when your phone's actually in your pocket and you can't see the screen. You reach in to turn up the volume but nothing happens.

Comment: I disagree, the *worst* is that they don't popover full screen apps like Netflix, so upping volume does nothing and you have to back out to home, dismiss it, open Netflix, open the movie again, and rebuffer.

Comment: The app [Fine Volume Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=opotech.finevolumev2) claims to do this.  Go into the app's settings and set the headphones warning threshold to 100%.  However, it did not work for me on an un-rooted Galaxy S4, so it might require rooting, as claimed elsewhere.  (Discovered [here](http://www.dvorak.org/blog/2014/06/09/how-to-disable-android-high-volume-warning-nannyware/).)

Comment: The Nanny State doesn't care if you own high impedance headphones (they're quieter on battery-powered devices), or headphones with a hardware volume control built-in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This limitation is baked into the Android OS, so the solution almost universal.
You need to root your device first... Search for an applicable rooting method that goes with your device and root it.
Then check out the link below. The author says "It works by simply setting the config_safe_media_volume_enabled system parameter to false at boot time. Because it uses the Xposed framework, it is device and rom independent"

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2338474

Answer (score 1):

(Some say) you can use `Hearing Saver` to disable (as a side-effect) the annoying warning; see [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jakebasile.android.hearingsaver&hl=de)