# Set maximum audio level, don't need alert message

Tags: android, audio

I have an audio app which will drive an external audio amplifier. In the code I set the maximum audio level:

int maxAudioVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREA M_MUSIC);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_M USIC,maxAudioVolume,0);

If I plug in the amplifier, then always the following alert is issued:
Raise volume above recommended level?

This is becoming irritating. Does anybody know how the alert can be avoided? Actually, this issue has been addressed in other forums, and sometimes it was solved, but always by using some app. Thus it should be possible, but the question is: how?

Wouter Boeke

Answer (score 1):

See this:
[Disable sound safe level notification in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179788/disable-sound-safe-level-notification-in-android) & [xda-developers; Unsafe Volume - disable safe media volume popup/check](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2338474)

Basically you need to root your phone, and set `config_safe_media_volume_enabled` at boot time to false. Which happens I think if the user clicks ok, you can't get rid of it without root.

Comment: Why is it needed to install the huge XPosed Framework just to set one bit of info at boot time? Can we do this just editing a file in `/sys` or something?